# how to render an image from the code repo in github pull request body

Tags: github, markdown, pull-request

We have a template to render the body of the Pull Request in the code repo.

we would need to render an image from the code repo as part of the Pull Request body markdown.

```markdown
![instruction screenshot](path-to-image)
```

it is not obvious how to define the path to the image.

there is a doc about [show images in github README file](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-readmes#relative-links-and-image-paths-in-readme-files)
however, it doesn't work for Pull Request body markdown.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use github URL link to the image.

```
https://github.com/account/repo-name/blob/branch-name/path/image.png?raw=true
```

IMPORTANT: remember to use the suffix `?raw=true` so that it links to the raw image file.

NOTE:
if you want to use the specific version of the image, use permanent link.

```
https://github.com/github/codeql/blob/b212af08a6cffbb434f3c8a2795a579e092792fd/img.png?raw=true
```